# Use cases where Javascript may be faster than compiled C code?

Tags: javascript, c, benchmarking, compiler-optimization

John Walker recently published an [update to his floating point benchmark](http://fourmilab.ch/fourmilog/archives/2017-10/001715.html), showing Javascript running faster than C code. He attributes this to "the poor performance of the new GCC trigonometric function libraries". Are there any other cases where Javascript may perform better than compiled C code? I am in particular thinking of areas applicable to machine learning and AI.

Comment: A *compiler* quality is not making *language* faster or slower. You can come up with a super-optimized C compiler. Or with some poorly written one. And the same code compiled by these will run differently. I can guarantee, a C compiler which will *always* generate code faster than JS is if not existent, but at least very possible.

Comment: This JS trigonometry functions use which kind of floating point type? Do they provide the same accuracy as the GCC's libc implemenation?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Valid point, but it is mostly theoretical. In practice, we live with the compilers we have. Walker's tests demonstrate that Javascript compilation in some cases exceeds what we can expect from C compilation, using generic tools. My question relates to this reality rather than what may be possible.

Comment: An interesting quote from that page: *"I suspect the Java engine which ultimately runs the JavaScript code of the benchmark uses different libraries which, although **perhaps less accurate** (but entirely adequate for this program), run much faster than those now used by GCC. "*

Comment: @alk Please read the linked article. It is detailed, and according to the author the accuracy is the same.

Comment: @BoPersson You're quoting somewhat out of context, ignoring the adequacy component of Walker's argument, leading to same accuracy of result.

Comment: I don't think so. If a lower precision math can be used for the same benchmark, but the author used the one with highest precision on GCC, meaning that the comparison was just not correct. Use a tool adequate for the task. And if you want maximum performance out of it, it should not be an overkill. So if GCC has a library which is sacrificing performance for accuracy, you can find another library or roll your own not doing it.

Comment: This is not a language issue, but completely related to the functions' implementations. Try adding Intel's C compiler and you'll be impressed.